# Rename AVI files from digicam

Tags: video, avi, rename

I use my Canon SD1100IS digicam to take pictures and video clips. When I upload to my computer, the folder has a bunch of IMG_nnnn.jpg, MVI_nnnn.AVI and MVI_nnnn.THM files.

The AVI files are in MJPEG format so the size is riduculously large. So I would like to use tools like VirtualDub to combine and compress the AVI files and it helps if all the AVI files have the same prefix and a running sequence number (MVI_1.avi, MVI_2.avi and so on)

How can I rename the AVI files in this fashion but at the same time preserve their original order so that things stay in the correct order when they are combined?

I looked at a few of the file renaming utilities out there but couldn't quite figure out how to do this easily. And if I can save the steps and apply them to a bunch of folders that would save a lot of time.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I generally rename all video clips and images to YYMMDD_HHMMSS.ext format to reflect the time they were shot.

- Maintains chronological order, even when using apps that don't read metadata,
- Removes redundant prefixes (extensions do the job just fine),
- Removes arbitrary sequence numbers (001, 002, etc.) (folders can hold separate shoots)
- Filename clashes are rare since I rarely use my cameras simultaneously.

I use [Downloader Pro](http://www.breezesys.com/Downloader/) to do the renames at the same time as I download from my flash cards or cameras, for its sheer simplicity, even though [Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/), which I use for everything else, can do the same.